# What's the maximum number for float on Rails validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following validation:

```
class Metrics
  validates :verbs_count, allow_nil: true, numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 1, less_than_or_equal_to: ? }
end
```

I would like to know what would be the maximum value of a float without losing precision. I know it seems like a question that should be easy to find an answer, but I'm not finding it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the docs (which are not in https://api.rubyonrails.org/ pages, but in the [code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/numericality.rb) in master):

> Validates whether the value of the specified attribute is numeric by
> trying to convert it to a float with `Kernel.Float` (if `only_integer`
> is false) or applying it to the regular expression `/\A[\+\-]?\d+\z/`
> (if `only_integer` is set to `true`).
>
> Precision of `Kernel.Float` values are guaranteed up to 15 digits.

The answer you're looking for is maybe here: "*Precision of Kernel.Float values are guaranteed up to 15 digits*" - as there's not a maximum number, then you can use whatever you want, just having in mind that greather numbers will loose precision.